# Can I deal damage to Hornet Nest multiple times before it dies?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a [Hornet Nest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hornet%20Nest) on the battlefield, can I cast 2x [Lightning Axe](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lightning%20Axe) on it to get 10 tokens? Or does the creature die between the first Lightning Axe and the space that the opponent has to respond? I think I can play as many instants as I want on the same creature before the stack resolves and the creature dies, right?

Comment: Edited title and grammar and formatting for clarity.

Comment: "Can I play multiple spells before my opponent gets a chance to respond?" is a unique question as far as I can tell. "When does my creature die if multiple spells would kill it?" is a duplicate of [Toughness and the Stack](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/24985/6692), so you might look there for information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is your turn, you may cast two instances of Lightning Axe (or any other instant) before your opponent gets priority. However, they do not resolve until your opponent has a chance to respond.

The order is:

1. You get priority
2. You cast Lightning Axe, choosing targets and paying the costs; Lightning Axe is on the stack
3. You intentionally retain priority.
4. You cast Lightning Axe, choosing targets and paying the costs; second Lightning Axe is on stack.
5. You get priority, you pass
6. Opponent gets priority, they may cast a spell.
7. Opponent passes priority.
8. Second Lightning Axe checks if the target is still legal. It is, it resolves. Creature has lethal damage.
   a. 5 Damage has been dealt to Hornet Nest, so next time priority would be given, ability that creates 5 Hornet tokens would be put on stack.
9. State-based actions are checked, creature dies.
10. Ability that creates 5 Hornet tokens goes on stack. (It resolves)
11. You get priority, pass
12. Opponent gets priority, pass.
13. First Lightning Axe checks if target is still legal.  It is not, so it fizzles. No damage is dealt to Hornet Nest

Final result: 5 Hornet tokens

Comment: Note that (3)  doesn't happen by default in tournaments. You must explicitly retain priority.

Comment: Why does it matter whose turn it is?

Comment: @diego The original question seemed to me that he wanted to do it before the opponent could respond.

Comment: It doesn't matter whose turn it is though, when you cast a spell you always get priority afterwards. It is after a spell resolves that the AP always gets priority.

Answer (score 2):

While you can cast 2x Lightning Axe, both targeting the Hornet Nest, both of them will not deal damage to the Hornet Nest. After the first one resolves, the Hornet Nest will die, and then when the second one resolves, it will be countered (fizzle) because its target no longer exists.

State-based effects are checked by the game in between each thing on the stack resolving. So the stack would build up and tear down like this (assuming it is currently your turn):

1. Cast Lightning Axe(1), targeting Hornet Nest.
2. In response, cast Lightning Axe(2), targeting Hornet Nest.
3. Both players pass priority.
4. Lighting Axe(2) resolves, dealing 5 damage to Hornet Nest and triggering Hornet Nest's triggered ability.
5. Hornet Nest dies as a state-based action.
6. Hornet Nest's triggered ability is placed on the stack.
7. Both players pass priority.
8. Hornet Nests's tirggered ability resolves, giving you 5 token creatures.
9. Both players pass priority.
10. Lightning Axe(1) tries to resolve, but is countered because it has no legal target.